# Display products of similar category RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Four models.

Product
Category
Categorization
Images

Product.rb

```
has_many  :images 
has_many  :categorizations
has_many  :categories, :through => :categorizations
```

Category.rb

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :products, :through => :categorizations
```

Categorization.rb

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :product
```

Image.rb

```
belongs_to :product
```

When a user clicks to see a product, I want to have a section on the bottom that shows images similar products (based on same category/categories).

I guess my problem is that there are so many nested relationships that I don't know how to extract the relationships out.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think of what object you are currently working with and what object you need to access. In this case I assume you set up `@product` in the controller, and it seems that you want a collection `@similar_products` that you then loop through on the bottom of the page.

We have a product to work with at the beginning. From this, we want products that are in the same categories as the product. So, in your controller do

```
@similar_products = @product.categories.inject({}) do |result_hash, category|
    result_hash[category.name.to_sym] => category.products.reject {|p| p == @product}
    result_hash
end
```

So what we end up with is something that looks like this:

```
{:category_1 => [product1, product2, product3], :category_2 => [product4,product5]...}
```

I might recommend limiting the number of products for each category to something like 5 by changing the result_hash assignment to

```
result_hash[category.name.to_sym] => category.products[0..4]
```

Now in your view you can loop through the products by category if you like:

```
<% @similar_products.each do |k,product_array| # remember that the key is the name and the value is an array %>
    <% product_array.each do |product| %>
        <img src="<%= product.image.path %>" />
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: There's `with_object` instead of `inject` to avoid ugly `result_hash` constructions.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I have several questions.

Comment: The first is that I changed the `result_hash[category.name.to_sym] => category.products.reject {|p| p == @product}` to `result_hash[category.name.to_sym] = category.productss.order('rand()').limit(4).reject { |p| p == @product}`. But the issue is that even though I limit it to 4 items, it continues to show more items at times when I refresh the page.

Comment: Second question is, if i have product two that belongs to the same two categories as product 1, how do I prevent product 2 from showing up twice in the similar products? I tried adding uniq! to the end of this `result_hash[category.name.to_sym] = category.productss.order('rand()').limit(4).reject { |p| p == @product}` but it returned an error.

Comment: I'm not sure about question 1, but for question 2 it looks like you are applying `uniq!` at the wrong place. You need to apply it to the whole hash with something after the whole inject like `@similar_products = @similar_products.to_a.flatten.uniq` which will leave you with an array like `[:cat_one,product1,product2,:cat_two,product3,product4]`.

Comment: @Tass would you mind showing an example of using that here, I had never used it. When I looked it up, it appears that it is a different inject syntax, is that correct?

Comment: `enum.with_object({}) {|(*args), hash| hash[key] = value }`